# Functionality missing in the Python ecosystem but present in R's

Tags: r, python, software

The PyData ecosystem is growing quickly but it still has some important gaps in relation to what one can find in R. I believe some examples are survival analysis and to some extent grammars of graphics (although this gap is being filled quickly with [Vincent](https://github.com/wrobstory/vincent), [Bokeh](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/bokeh)  and [ggplot](https://github.com/yhat/ggplot))

What are the **specific areas where the PyData ecosystem is still lagging in relation to R's**? In other words, what are some specific features that a statistician/data scientist would miss/like to see in the PyData system that are present in R's?

Comment: There's a recent library in Python for survival analysis. https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/lifelines Glms and time-series is done with statsmodels, but it could be much more comprehensive. R has a breadth of libraries for nearly every topic. Same with Matlab. Why do you ask?

Comment: This question is too local. It is basically loses value everytime a new library for R or Python is released.